# How can I get the correct path to the ConnectionManager in CakePHP?

Tags: php, cakephp

I'm trying to get the correct path loaded for the ConnectionManager inside 
a controller, however at current I'm not having much luck.

I'm using this:

```
  App::uses('ConnectionManager', '/lib/Cake/Model/');
```

and CakePHP is the default application in my root, but so far I can't seem to trace - it wants to try to locate it through the non-absolute path.
What am I doing wrong? I've confirmed that ConnectionManager.php is present and properly loaded on the server, but all I get are 'not found/not defined'.

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: I am... trying to get ConnectionManager initialized through the correct use of App::uses, but cannot get it pointed at the right folders?

Comment: Okay, I haven't found an answer - still searching, but do feel somewhat stupid. I was looking at the documentation for ConnectionManager under 3.x beta and using 2.x Stable.

Comment: Success! Entirely my fault, I was after 2.x documentation and reading 3.0 documentation. Maybe a suggestion to the team... add "Beta" to the Book for 3.0? When I downloaded I grabbed 2.7, but the book defaults to 3.0.

Comment: 3.x isn't beta anymore, it's stable since like 4+ months.

Comment: You still haven't described/demonstrated an actual problem only [focussed on your chosen solution](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: Also note if you're just starting out - you should consider using 3.x, it is [the _current_ version](http://cakephp.org/).

Comment: Thank you, I will. It's a little confusing seeing the download list. I got my copy a few days ago and grabbed the top one that was 2.7, and today saw the 3.1 beta upload.